# Closed Work items show on backlog when In progress filter is turned on

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

With our Azure DevOps backlog, if we enable the "In Progress Items" filter, we also see closed work items still on our backlog.

[image]

[image]

With the Boards Process set up, Closed is set as completed.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with the same configuration of your process; however, my `Closed` backlogs disappeared as soon as I changed its state to `Closed` and refreshed my page. From the screenshot, we could see your UI had enabled [New Boards Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-202-update#new-boards-hubs-now-available-in-public-preview) preview feature. Would you test to disable the preview feature and see if the issue still persists? If the issue is gone, you may enable the preview feature back and try to reproduce again.

Comment: @AlvinZhao I tried turning the New Boards preview feature on and off and still see the same results.